# ValueError:Input 0 is incompatible with layer lstm_1: expected ndim=3,found ndim=4

Tags: tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

```
class SmallerVGGNet:
    @staticmethod
    def build(width, height, depth, classes, finalAct="softmax"):
        # initialize the model along with the input shape to be
        # "channels last" and the channels dimension itself
        model = Sequential()
        inputShape = (height, width, depth)
        chanDim = -1
        units = 1

        if K.image_data_format() == "channels_first":
            inputShape = (depth, height, width)
            chanDim = 1
 # CONV => RELU => POOL
        model.add(Conv2D(16, (3, 3), padding="same", input_shape=inputShape,))
        model.add(BatchNormalization(axis=chanDim))
        model.add(Activation("relu"))
 model.add(
            LSTM(128, activation='tanh', return_sequences=True, use_bias=True, kernel_initializer="glorot_uniform"))
 # softmax classifier
        model.add(Flatten())
        model.add(Dropout(0.5))

        print(model.summary())
        return model
```

How to fix this error ?  str(x.shape.as_list()))
ValueError: Input 0 of layer lstm is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=3, found ndim=4. Full shape received: [None, 16, 16, 128]

Answer (score 0):

LSTM expects inputs: A 3D tensor with shape `[batch, timesteps, feature]`

**Working sample code**

```
inputs = tf.random.normal([32, 10, 8])
lstm = tf.keras.layers.LSTM(4)
output = lstm(inputs)
print(output.shape)
```

**Output**

```
(32, 4)
```